# How To Mock Chained MongoDB Function With Jest

Tags: javascript, mongodb, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to mock MongoClient's `insertMany` functions. With this mock I won't use real mongo db instead of it I will use mock implementation with Jest. However I am having an error like

> DbConnection.db(...).collection is not a function

```
await DbConnection.db().collection(this.collectionName).insertMany(logs);
```

## Mock

```
const DbConnection = {
  db: () => jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() =>({
    collection: () => jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() =>({
      insertMany: () => {
        return { success: true }
      },
    })),
  })),
  close: async () => true
};
```

## Error

```
DbConnection.db(...).collection is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [mockFn.mockReturnThis()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnthis)

```
const DbConnection = {
  db: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  collection: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  insertMany: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({success: true})
}
```

Then, you can chain call the methods:

```js
const actual = await DbConnection.db().collection().insertMany();
// The value of actual is: {success: true}
```